# Collection data not found

Tags: oracle, plsql

Seeking your assistance with the following error,

Basically I have a collection

```
type bundle_group IS TABLE of tablename.GROUP%type INDEX BY binary_integer;
SELECT group
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO bundleGroup
    FROM tablename
   WHERE rownum <= 10000 AND ID = 'myname';
```

bundleGroup bundle_group;
wherein if i try `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bundleGroup(1))`; it will return a value.
but when I use a counter like this

```
counter = bundleGroup.first;
bundleGroup(counter);
```

sometimes it will return a no data found error.

is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

> sometimes it will return a no data found error.

It looks as if *sometimes* collection doesn't contain anything.

For example, this *works*:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type bundle_group is table of dept.deptno%type index by binary_integer;
  3    bundlegroup bundle_group;
  4  begin
  5    select deptno bulk collect into bundlegroup from dept;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(bundlegroup(1));
  7  end;
  8  /
10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, if query doesn't return anything, then there's nothing to display (note line #5 and condition `where 1 = 2`):

```
SQL> declare
  2    type bundle_group is table of dept.deptno%type index by binary_integer;
  3    bundlegroup bundle_group;
  4  begin
  5    select deptno bulk collect into bundlegroup from dept where 1 = 2;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(bundlegroup(1));
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 6


SQL>
```

What to do? Don't display anything if collection is empty:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type bundle_group is table of dept.deptno%type index by binary_integer;
  3    bundlegroup bundle_group;
  4  begin
  5    select deptno bulk collect into bundlegroup from dept where 1 = 2;
  6    if bundlegroup.count > 0 then
  7       dbms_output.put_line(bundlegroup(1));
  8    else
  9       dbms_output.put_line('Empty collection');
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /
Empty collection

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```